# Display error message below input field

Tags: html

Is there any native HTML element which can be used to show a text under an input field ? something like a `label` ?

Right now, I have an `input` field in middle of a form and I want to show an error message below this it if a user puts some wrong value inside that field.

Answer (score 13):

For `show an error message below this it if a user puts some wrong value inside that field`, yes you are talking about showing validation errors. There are two types of these validation error messages available in HTML 5:

1. Automatic messages
2. Custom messages

### Automatic Messages

Automatic messages simply use HTML5 form attributes. But the disadvantage is they are automatic, not customizable by default. For example if you require an email, the default error message on Firefox, when you specify an email input and fail to write one: `Please enter an email address`, you would not be able to change this using just HTML and CSS.

Another disadvantage is the default message depends on the browser locale, so if for example you are borrowing your friend's French computer to view an English website, those default error messages will then display in French:

[image: screenshot Firefox rendering of error message]

Source: Mozilla Developer Network article: [Data form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation)

### Custom messages

As [Data form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation) says:

> To customize the appearance and text of these messages, you must use JavaScript; there is no way to do it using just HTML and CSS.
>
> HTML5 provides [the constraint validation API](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-constraint-validation-api) to check and customize the state of a form element.

The example from [Data form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation):

```html
<form>
  <label for="mail">I would like you to provide me an e-mail</label>
  <input type="email" id="mail" name="mail">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

```js
var email = document.getElementById("mail");

email.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
  if (email.validity.typeMismatch) {
    email.setCustomValidity("I expect an e-mail, darling!");
  } else {
    email.setCustomValidity("");
  }
});
```

So yes, you can have messages below the input in HTML5. Just beware that they will either be the automatic type, or, to customize, you need to look into using the constraint validation API to write your own messages using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net core

```
 <div class="form-group row col-md-12 field-space">
       <label asp-for="Code" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label required"></label>
       <input asp-for="Code" class="form-control form-control-sm col-sm-3" placeholder="Code" />
       <span asp-validation-for="Code" class="text-danger col-sm-4"></span>
    </div>
```

The above code will align `label` `Text-field` and `validation message` in a row
if You want the validation message below try the code below

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label asp-for="Code" class="col-form-label required"></label>
   <input asp-for="Code" class="form-control form-control-sm " placeholder="Code"/>
    <span asp-validation-for="Code" class="text-danger "></span>
</div>
```